# Как клиентам получить IP-адрес от DHCP-сервера в другой сети?

Tags: linux, сеть, маршрутизация, router, dhcp

Всем привет.

Такая беда: есть сервер DHCP с Debian на борту, пакет isc-dhcp-server на 2 пула. Первый пул обеспечивает адресами клиентов в подсети самого сервера. Второй пул должен обеспечить адресами другую сеть. Между клиентами и сервером стоит шлюз, который и портит всю картину. В общем по рисунку будет все понятно.

Пробовал добавлять в маршруты на сервере: route add -host 255.255.255.255 eth0
Все сети маршрутизированы протоколом OSPF, пинги удачные. На маршрутизаторах форвардинг включен.

Заранее признателен за помощь.

P.S. - все маршрутизаторы на Linux.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не запамятовал есть такая штука, называется dhcp relay. Вот его надо установить на шлюз или включить в коммутаторе, если имеется такая возможность

Comment: К предыдущему могу добавить, что можно копнуть в сторону опции `dhcp proxy`.

Comment: @Sergey пробовал использовать isc-dhcp-relay на CLI-GW, указав оба сетевых интерфейса и IP-адрес сервера DHCP. В isc-dhcp-server запросы приходят, но адрес клиенты все равно не получают.

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в том, что первая пара сообщений DHCP (DHCPDISCOVER / DHCPOFFER) являются широковещательными и ваш шлюз их не пропускает из одной подсети в другую.

Comment: iptables - интерфейсы маскарадятся на MainGw? в sysctl.conf - форвардинг пакетов по ipv4 разрешен? желательно во всех шлюзах...         net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
 iptables: -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 1):

DHCP будет фильтроваться шлюзом всегда. Вам лучше использовать на шлюзе [DHCP relay](http://yourtoolbox.blogspot.ru/2013/01/dhcp-forwarding-with-relay-server.html)